# Creating layer that intersects two attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, intersection

I have one polygon feature class.

I am trying within this feature class to show clashes of polygons by specific dates.

Does anyone know how the best method to do this within ArcGIS Pro and then ensure it is picked up in real time?

I was thinking to do this with FME and it is straight forward with FME but I am wondering if Pro has another way of doing this.

Is there a way to do this with ArcGIS online also using arcade expressions?

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online in this particular question.

Comment: I was thinking of using ArcGIS Pro to see if it would be published as a layer but it maybe possible to do some in AGOL so hence I thought i will ask which might work out better.  Prefrence would be AGOL but either option i am open to exploring.